# Internet Explorer 9 showing as Not Applicable in WSUS for Vista Machines

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus, windows-vista

I imported Windows Internet Explorer 9 into WSUS using the Microsoft Update Catalog web page. I then approved the updates.
All the Windows 7 machines installed the update correctly.
The Windows Vista machines did not.  When checking the WSUS Console, those machines have reported that the update is Not Applicable.

When I run Windows Update from a client machine, IE9 is not offered.

I am not sure what to do to make the Vista machines see the update as "Needed"

Comment: Does Vista have SP2?  Have you checked to see if it already has IE9?

Comment: Do the Vista machines have Service Pack 2 installed? I don't think IE9 is avalible for Vanilla Vista, SP1, or older Windows Versions.

Comment: Yes they all have SP2.  I should have mentioned that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I would make sure that Windows Vista x64 is at Service Pack 2 because you can't install IE9 on less.  Also, it's possible that Vista already has IE 9...have you checked that?

**edited to add**

The file %WinDir%\WindowsUpdate.log can also offer some clues.

Comment: Yes they all have SP2. I should have mentioned that earlier.